# adding a custom plugin to google-fluentd

Tags: google-cloud-platform, fluentd

I need to capture file descriptors for a given process. This is simular to what collectd's processes plugin does, but need to get this on the fluentd, google-fluentd specifically rails.

I've added my plugin under /etc/google-fluentd/plugin directory and no luck, it is not getting registered.  I've even moved under `/opt/google-fluentd/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fluentd-1.7.4/lib/fluent/plugin` still no luck. Out of desperation I have also tried renaming in_tail.rb to in_tail2.rb and tail plugin is gone.

```
2020-08-14 18:28:16 -0700 [error]: fluent/log.rb:362:error: config error file="/etc/google-fluentd/google-fluentd.conf" error_class=Fluent::ConfigError error="Unknown input plugin 'tail'. Run 'gem search -rd fluent-plugin' to find plugins"
```

Which tells me that there is some other place where plugin must be mentioned.  Is it too naive to think that I can just write a single file plugin under /etc/google-fluentd/plugin?

Answer (score 2):

After a few hours of going up and down the call stack in the fluentd trying to figure out the logic behind why and which plugins fluentd loads here is what I figured out.

@type  has to match registration call and filename!

ie i had used

```
@type fc_count
```

my filename was
/etc/google-fluentd/in_fd.rb
with

```
 Fluent::Plugin.register_input('fd_count', self)
```

Although type and registration matched, fluent couldn't match file path to plugin/in_fd.rb as it loads configuration.  Basically if you don't use a plugin it won't load it and the way it determines it is by going through config.  This is the reason why when I renamed an existing input plugin it was no longer found.

Comment: This is an interesting problem and answer. Can you modify your answer to clearly show what you changed to solve the problem?

Comment: Hey Anton, thanks for the information!
Adding to your posts, I would like to share these links with you:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Thanks again for the info!